# R: How do I call a dataframe column using an alias?

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function for getting test error from a linear regression model.

My input is a list that has each part of the model

```
model.1 <- list("medv","~.","Boston_Ready")
names(model.1) <- c("response", "input","dataset")
```

My function calculates the validation set error from that input

```
ValidationError <- function(model){
    df <- get(model$dataset)
    formula <- paste(model$response,model$input)
    response <- model$response       

    #validation set
    train <- sample(nrow(df), (nrow(df)/2))
    fit_train <- lm(formula,data=df,subset=train)
    Valid_MSE <- mean(df[-train,]$response - predict(fit_train, df[-train,]))^2
    print(Valid_MSE)    
}
```

The error reads `Error: attempt to apply non-function`

It is because the definition of `Valid_MSE` includes `df[-train,]$response`

I've also tried

```
df[-train,]$get(response)
df[-train,]$paste(response)
```

How can I call a particular columns from the dataframe? Can I do it using my list alias "response"?

Comment: try `df[-train, response]`